# How can we add extra label to Prometheus metrics?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator

Suppose we are collecting the same metrics for one month and now we want to modify the metrics to have extra label (in the old data as well), how can we do that.
Existing metric:

```
mongodb_exporter_last_scrape_duration_seconds{instance="127.0.0.1:9216",job="mongo"}
```

Want to change that to:

```
mongodb_exporter_last_scrape_duration_seconds{cluster="stage", instance="127.0.0.1:9216",job="mongo"}
```

Answer (score 17):

```
- job_name: 'your_job'                 
  honor_labels: true                         
  static_configs:                     
  - targets:                          
    - '127.0.0.1'          
    labels:                           
      cluster: 'stage'
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Comment: That will add the label "stage" to the newly scraped data. But I want to add that label to previously collected data points as well.

Comment: This is for static configurations, if i have to add a label to my kubernetes_sd_configs , where should i add this additional label?

Comment: Please give explanation of your snippet!

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to change the labels on old metrics in Prometheus.

The storage is only updated by new scrapes and then it becomes immutable.

Answer (score 6):

if you have a service discovery config, you can also add labels in the relabels_config

```
relabel_configs:
  - target_label: cluster
    replacement: stage
```

Answer (score 4):

Prometheus doesn't provide the ability to add new labels to historical time series. But it is possible to add missing labels during queries with [label_replace()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_replace) function:

```
label_replace(
  mongodb_exporter_last_scrape_duration_seconds,
  "cluster",
  "staging",
  "cluster",
  ""
)
```

This `label_replace()` call adds `cluster="staging"` label only if the `cluster` label is missing in the original time series selected with `mongodb_exporter_last_scrape_duration_seconds` [series selector](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors).

Answer (score 0):

https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_replace
https://medium.com/@texasdave2/replace-and-remove-a-label-in-a-prometheus-query-9500faa302f0

In fact, the label_replace method only add a new label to metrics but not replace. So I can use this method to add a new label if you do not want to change prometheus.yml config.

For your case:

mongodb_exporter_last_scrape_duration_seconds{instance="127.0.0.1:9216",job="mongo"}

label_replace(mongodb_exporter_last_scrape_duration_seconds{instance="127.0.0.1:9216",job="mongo"}, **"cluster", "stage", "(.*)")**