# How to add extra labels to all metrics

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator

I actually have 3 GCP kubernetes clusters with prometheus operator installed on each of them. I'm trying to figure out how to add extra environment labels to all metrics in order to explicitly know from which cluster the metrics are coming from.
For some metrics like kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores or kube_pod_info my labels are not setted.

PS: my config already have this: [How can we add extra label to Prometheus metrics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47628532/how-can-we-add-extra-label-to-prometheus-metrics)